# Turned off breaker, power consumption almost cut in half. No idea what it's for

Tags: circuit-breaker

My house was remodeled in 2010 and I mention this only because I have two breakers labeled "Dishwasher" and I assume there must have been some rewiring done. Flip one and nothing happens, flip the other and the dishwasher turns off.

The trouble is when you flip off the first breaker that does "nothing", my power consumption drops from 1.7kW to .9kW. I can't for the life of me find anything not working that was working prior to flipping the breaker.

Could anybody provide some insight what could be happening?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. I'd leave that first breaker off; having close to a kW of power dissipation happening in some unknown (and unexpected) location could be extremely dangerous.

Comment: At this time of year, I wonder whether it's powering roof or pipe heating... Might be worth the cost of tracing it before you assume you can live without it.

Comment: Leave it off, check all refrigerators and freezers for operation, then wait until you find what's not working anymore.  My guess is "dishwasher" got moved, and the old location didn't get relabeled.

Comment: Thanks for the quick feedback, it's greatly appreciated. I live in a mild climate (SF Bay area), so it wouldn't be something like roof heating. I'm going to leave it shut off for now and see if something turns up, all of the obvious things (fridge, oven, hot water, bedroom/bathroom lights/outlets, etc.) all seem to be working.

Comment: You wrote quantities in kWh — in what time period? Or did you mean kW as another comment assumed? How are you measuring the power?

Comment: @KevinReid My guess is reading the display on the power meter, if it's a newer one.

Comment: Heat pump or aircon unit? It's not uncommon to have the outdoor unit powered separately from the indoor, so the fan and controller will still work even if you turned off the outdoor.

Comment: So is the ~800Watt draw continuous, or intermittent? Could be a booster heater for the dishwasher, though that's uncommon in a home installation. Could be a sump or sewage pump.

Comment: kW is correct, I got the units mixed up from the meter readings. Furnace works fine, no A/C in the home. No sump/sewage pump (ranch on a slab foundation in regular suburban neighborhood).

Comment: The draw was continuous for the hour I was monitoring the meter while I was shutting off breakers to see what was causing my high electric bill.

Comment: Any vacant houses next door?  Bay Area yes, but many properties are held by foreign investors, and are unoccupied because they don't want to deal with rental properties.  A small marijuana grow operation might have moved in there.  Load would be about right for 2 400W metal halide lights. Houses are so close that some half-buried 14-2 Romex might go unnoticed.  It was only JUST legalized.

Comment: Is there a "on demand" hot water outlet at the sink? These little guys pull a fair amount and are usually close to the dishwasher, garbage disposal outlets if separately wired.

Comment: Please post up when you figure this out - that's alot of power to not know where it's going.  You might also try one of those signal generator devices to trace the wire from the breaker.

Comment: I figured out the first "dishwasher" breaker was controlling the floor heating in the master bathroom. The floor heating to the other bathroom in the house was controlled by its own breaker.

Comment: The problem now is even though I flipped that breaker back on, my power usage on the meter is down to .4kW this morning. I couldn't be more confused what's going on.

Comment: I went down this path of figuring out what was consuming so much electricity, because my bill last month was over $400 for a 1900 sqft house :-(

Comment: Your in-floor heating might be variable (or the thermostat might be screwy). If you really wanted to go for it and felt handy, you could get a clamp ammeter to monitor actual current.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because you have two bathrooms with electric floor heat and are (no longer) wondering where 800kW are going.

Answer (score 1):

For posterity (and future searches), I'll try to combine the suggestions from comments and briefly summarize the outcome. Any edits are welcome, especially if you feel I've misconstrued ideas. This is tagged as a community wiki.

- The first suggestion was to leave the breaker off until the issue was better understood, as this could have been a dangerous and well hidden electrical fault.
- Being winter, pipe or roof heating was suspected. (We later learned
  that the OP is in a mild climate, with overnight temperatures a bit
  below freezing at this time of year.)
- Suggestion to 'leave it off' and start hunting for things that don't
  work. (Particular reminder to check fridges/freezers after turning
  off circuit breakers. Nobody likes a freezer full of spoiled food.)
- Suggestion about heat pump/AC unit. (Not applicable in this case.)
- Suggestion about booster heater for dishwasher, sump pump, or sewage
  pump. (Not applicable in this case.)
- Suggestion about someone illegally tapping power to a nearby house.
  (Not applicable in this case.)
- Suggestion about on-demand hot water. (Not applicable in this case.)
- Suggestion to use a signal tracer (such as a Fluke Networks Pro 3000)
  to follow the circuit.

Resolution (somewhat): it turned out to be an in-floor heating unit in a bathroom. There are still unexplained variations in power consumption (suggestion to get a clamp meter); perhaps the OP will be able to provide more information if anything comes up.